# Django models.py transactions rollback/commit problem

Tags: django, transactions, models

I read the documentation on transactions , but still a bit lost how should i really do it.
Lets say i have **class Book(name,content,left_key,right_key,level)** in models.py with methods , which stores book content as nested sets. The main method i want use is

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def add_node(self,right,level):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE cms_Book  SET left_key = left_key + 2, right_key = right_key + 2 WHERE left_key > %s",[right])
    cursor.execute("UPDATE cms_Book SET right_key = right_key + 2 WHERE right_key >= %s AND left_key < %s ",[right,right])
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cms_Book SET left_key = %s, right_key = %s + 1, level = %s + 1, content='roar'",[right,right,level])
```

But as insertion mainly depends on keys passed from template as parameters i need to check if correct keys are inserted .Even if for example wrong keys are inserted , node will still be added and nothing will break and no exception will occur but the logic will break which is not very good, in case i need to get specific nodes and not all of them.

So i have several other methods to check whether logic is correct or not. Here is one of them:

```
 def check_count(self):
    q = Book.objects.aggregate(min_key = Min('left_key'),max_key= Max('right_key'),count_all = Count('id'))
    return q
```

What i need is kind of execute all the actions in add_node method , then check if the logic didn't break with check methods , if it didn't ,commit everything  otherwise rollback. What i kind of don't understand is, if i use try except block  i need db to produce some kind of error/exception which it won't , or for example to do:

```
   if (check_my_table_for_all_different_keys == none):
           transactions.commit
   else:
           transactions.rollback
```

**check_my_table_for_all_different_keys** - returns nothing if all keys are unique , otherwise returns id of objects which are identical or which have same keys. Also i am not sure how exactly should part look where i commit all 3 transactions , in case my logic on if - else structure is correct , which i think is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The django documentation on [transaction management](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transaction-management-in-views) shows two possible ways. The examples assume you have a `valid` function (e.g. your `check_my_table_for_all_different_keys`) which validates the current state of the database, and returns false when the data is wrong.

**use `commit_on_success` (as you currently do)**

This way the pending transaction is committed once the function successfully returns. When an exception is raised it is rolled back.

```
@transaction.commit_on_success
def add_node(self, right, level):
  # insert/update entries
  if not valid():
      raise Exception('invalid state')
```

The calling code needs to handle this exception, but knows if the node has been added successfully.

**use `commit_manually`**

This is more explicit, in a way that you have to commit or rollback when appropriate. Your example allready goes that direction.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def add_node(self, right, level):
  # insert/update entries
  if valid():
      transaction.commit()
  else:
      transaction.rollback()
```

No exception is raised, 'errors' are silenced. The transaction has been committed if everything was correct, or rolled back otherwise.

Comment: Problem 2) when i tried to use `@transaction.commit_on_success` nothing got saved to db
Problem 3) will transaction.commit()  save all three queries at once ? Because i used `transaction.commit_unless_managed()` on every query i executed to save to db.
Problem 4) How to correctly add code to comments :D because `code`  works only for one line , as far as i understood.

Comment: It looks for a check_difference function in the global namespace, and cannot find it. Did you implement it as a class method? Then maybe you want it to read `check = self.check_difference(self)`.

Comment: Thank you. Works great. Still am not sure why `transaction.commit_on_success` didn't work , but i guess it's not really related now to this question. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Django 1.9 +

Django provides a single API to control database transactions.

atomic(using=None, savepoint=True)[source]¶
Atomicity is the defining property of database transactions. atomic allows us to create a block of code within which the atomicity on the database is guaranteed. If the block of code is successfully completed, the changes are committed to the database. If there is an exception, the changes are rolled back.

atomic blocks can be nested. In this case, when an inner block completes successfully, its effects can still be rolled back if an exception is raised in the outer block at a later point.

atomic is usable both as a decorator:

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
def viewfunc(request):
    # This code executes inside a transaction.
    do_stuff()
```

Answer (score 0):

Now that everything works fine. I guess i should provide a full code , if anyone will ever be stupid like me and get stuck =).
  So we have a **class Book(name,content,left_key,right_key,level) in models.py** with methods:

> **check_difference** returns false if all keys are unique , otherwise it returns true because all pairs which contain same keys are fetched and put into **q** variable. So if anything is returned  len(q) is > 0

```
def check_difference(self):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT t1.id, COUNT(t1.id) AS rep, MAX(t3.right_key) AS max_right \
                    FROM cms_Book AS t1, cms_Book AS t2, cms_Book AS t3\
                    WHERE t1.left_key <> t2.left_key \
                    AND t1.left_key <> t2.right_key \
                    AND t1.right_key <> t2.left_key \
                    AND t1.right_key <> t2.right_key \
                    GROUP BY t1.id \
                    HAVING max_right <> SQRT(4 * rep + 1) + 1 ")
    q = cursor.fetchall()
    if len(q) > 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

> Here i execute 3 queries  , check the table for correctness and if everything is ok , all keys are unique and **check_difference** returns false then we commit all queries and save to database , otherwise rollback.

```
@transaction.commit_manually
def add_node(self,right,level):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("UPDATE cms_Book  SET left_key = left_key + 2, right_key = right_key + 2 WHERE left_key > %s",[right])

    cursor.execute("UPDATE cms_Book SET right_key = right_key + 2 WHERE right_key >= %s AND left_key < %s ",[right,right])

    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO cms_Book SET left_key = %s, right_key = %s + 1, level = %s + 1, content='roar'",[right,right,level])
    check = self.check_difference()
    if check == True:
        transaction.rollback()
    else:
        transaction.commit()
```